# functional forward checking implementation

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I would like to implement the [forward checking search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-ahead_%28backtracking%29) in a functional way in scheme. Forward checking search is a depth first search that chooses a variable at each node of a graph, tries all the values in the domain of this variable and recursively calls itself until a variable domain is empty or a solution is found. In pseudo code the algorithm is

```
bool ForwardChecking ()
   if no free variable then
      return true
   choose a free variable var
   for all values in the domain of var
      assign value to var
      update the domains of the free variables
      if no domain is empty or inconsistent then
        if (ForwardChecking ()) then
          return true
   return false
```

In my particular problem I have a vector where some of the elements have seteq representing the possible values that element can take and other elements have an integer. For example a 6x6 vector is

```
#(1 (seteq 2 4 6) 5 (seteq 2 3 6) (seteq 2 3 4 6) (seteq 3 4)
 (seteq 2 3 4) (seteq 2 4 6) (seteq 2 3 6) (seteq 2 3 6) 1 (seteq 3 4 5) 
 6 (seteq 1 2 5) (seteq 1 2 3) 4 (seteq 2 3 5) (seteq 1 3 5)
(seteq 2 3 5) (seteq 1 2 5) 4 (seteq 1 2 3) (seteq 2 3 5) 6
(seteq 2 4 5) 3 (seteq 1 2 6) (seteq 1 6) (seteq 4 6) (seteq 1 4)
(seteq 4)(seteq 1 4 6) (seteq 1 6) 5 (seteq 3 4 6) 2)
```

my goal is to figure out the integer that goes into the elements of the vector with seteq using forward checking.

My incomplete attempt at implementing the algorithm in scheme follows
(find-min-pos is a function that finds the positions of all elements of the vector with the smallest number of integers; vector-update is a function that sets one of those elements to one of the integers in its seteq)

```
(define (forward-checking vec)
   ; get list of position of elements of vec with smallest number of 
   ; seteq elements
   (define min-free-pos (find-min-pos vec))
   (cond
     ; if no free variable return true
     [(empty? min-free-pos) #t]
     ; pick a random element of min-free-pos
     [else
        (define free-elem-pos (list-ref min-free-pos (random (length min-free-pos))))
        ; find the vector element
        (define free-elem (board-ref board free-elem-pos))
        ; loop through all values that free-elem contains
        ; this is a seteq
        (for ([i (in-set free-elem)])
          (define vec2 (vector-update vec free-elem-pos i))
          ; the following is incorrect
          (if vec2
              if forward-checking vec2)
          )
        #f]
  ))
```

How to complete it? Is there a different (maybe more functional) way of implementing it?

Comment: Why does it need to be a random variable? Can't you choose the next one you haven't looked at?